# What's the reason why Controller methods return ActionResult? (ASP.NET Core Web API)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm pretty new to Web APIs. I observed that some methods return an `ActionResult`. Why is that? Isn't it enough returning, for example, a `CustomerDto` instead?

Returning ActionResult gives no clue about the actual object being returned. Do I miss something?

Comment: when you say it "gives no clue", it gives no clue to what?

Comment: Returning a payload of data in the response body is not the only thing you ever do in APIs. You may redirect, or send headers only, for example. The various classes derived from IActionResult are basically convenience classes for setting the desired status codes and headers.

Comment: It's just that, they are convenience classes that are as inconvenient as they are convenient, because for the main flow – returning a DTO – they obscure the code, not clarify it. Even for alternate flows they 'protect' you from the detail of http e.g. from writing `Response.StatusCode = 202; Response.ContentType = "text/json"` but is that really a helpful way to treat developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice the prebuild project of the .net core web api, not all functions return `ActionResult` or `IActionResult`. So yes, you can totally return something like `CustomerDto`. This way you can return an object as json, with the status code 200. However let's say your action is taking in some input and you are not always sure if there will be a valid output. In this case you will want to return status code 200 only if successful, 400 (badRequest) if the user sent invalid data or any other status code. This is the standard way of handling http requests.

So, by using `IActionResult` you can either return a `CustomerDto` object by using `return Json(customer)` or `return Ok(customer)`, or you can return use `BadRequest(myErrors)` when you run into errors.

Comment: Can't you return a Bad Request if you use a CustomerDto as return type? Isn't there any Exception type that is interpreted by ASP.NET Core as Bad Request, Not Found or Conflict?

Comment: I too was expecting a try catch exception earlier for that but until recently haven't found any. but yes there is a way to throw these responses with `CustomerDto`, but will be relatively complicated. you can check them here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters

Comment: Yes, you can have return type `CustomerDto` and still return a BadRequest ; or rathe, to be accurate, you can `Response.StatusCode = 400; return (CustomerDto)null;` And yes, that would make perfect sense for a WebApi controller and people have done that for years with webapi. Sometimes the MS out of the box code is there to show off fancy new options that aren't what most of us want.

Comment: No you can't do it by throwing an exception—because http has no concept of a thrown exception. The framework will catch it and instead return an http StatusCode 500 ("Internal Server Error") response. 
You _can_ write a global exception handler to recognise different exceptions thrown by your application, and use some lookup or transform to turn them into the most appropriate Http Status Code. I do this. I then also put some helpful description in the ReasonPhrase.

Answer (score 2):

Web API is a flexible platform - you can write simple APIs that always just return particular result types (such as your `CustomerDto`) or you can write more complex APIs that really do care about HTTP semantics and want to have more control over status codes, other HTTP headers, etc.

Or maybe your method is dealing with "resources" which have more complex representations that aren't easily modelled by a *single* DTO class in C#, and so you want the flexibility of multiple possible "return types".

If you don't want that level of control, yes, you can carry on and just return your DTO types. Nobody is (to the best of my knowledge) forcing you to use `ActionResult` instead.

Comment: Do you know a common case when using DTOs can be a problem?

Comment: @SuperJMN - it's not that returning DTOs is a *problem*, per se, more that returning a DTO is leaving a lot of decisions (status codes, caching, headers, etc) as their defaults.

Comment: I'm with @SuperJMN. Declaring methods returning DTOs is the simpler/clearer code. The whole `IActionResult` instead of `DTO` thing does not improve your ability to override defaults; it still comes down to setting `Response.StatusCode`, or Response Headers, or ReasonPhrase before the method returns

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core the former MVC "Controller"-class and Web Api "ApiController"-class where merged together to one "Controller"-class.
The ActionResult method, which is a classic MVC method and useful when building an MVC application, where also included in that merged and that's why
it's being available when also building a Web Api.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of designing your Web API. You can return CustomerDto, in your case. According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results), a Web API controller action can return any of the following:
 - void
 - HttpResponseMessage
 - IHttpActionResult
 - Some other type

By using IHttpActionResult, you can better control the Http Reponse code.

Comment: OK! so, for readability, I would choose to return DTOs, but then what are the problems of returning bare DTOs? Could I have some problematic restrictions?

Comment: in principal you need to throw proper http. error status messages on fail, and in your client you need to check if the http response has the status 200. If you simply have the return type DTOs, you will not be able to throw the right error messages

Comment: check this link for error messages https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: also for readability two alternates, 1. user a comment on top of the action, 2. if you want to ensure type safety and want to keep the return type as DTO then you can look up Action Filters